# Change color of the text in word document with paragraph.text.replace

Tags: python, python-docx

For a project I need to change a word in my word document.
I managed to do this with the following code:

```
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                if 'example' in paragraph.text:
                    paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace("example", "hello")
```

Now I want the word 'hello' to be in the same format (color, type etc) as the previous word 'example'. I found the following code but I can't figure out how I can apply it to my own project.

```
from docx.shared import RGBColor
document = Document()
run = document.add_paragraph().add_run('some text')
font = run.font
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x42, 0x24, 0xE9)
p=document.add_paragraph('aaa')
document.save('demo1.docx')
```

Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through this same problem. MS Word handles this formatting in a proprietary way. I've created a library that solves this problem. Take a look at https://github.com/ivanbicalho/python-docx-replace. There is an explanation of how MS Word handles this and how it was solved.